# Android ORMLite not setting foreign when saving or not refreshing

Tags: android, ormlite

**Introduction**

I have two entities :

Traitement

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "traitement", daoClass = TraitementNettoyageDAO.class)
public class TraitementEntity implements Parcelable {


    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private Collection<AnomalieNettoyageEntity> mListAnomalieNettoyage;

    public TraitementEntity() {
    }

    // omitting getter/setter and parcelable job
}
```

Anomalie

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "anomalies", daoClass = AnomalieDAO.class)
public class AnomalieEntity implements Parcelable {


    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String mIdAnomalie;


    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "traitementForeignId", foreignAutoRefresh = true, canBeNull = false)
    private TraitementEntity traitementForeign;

    // omitting getter/setter and parcelable job
}
```

I'm actually saving my traitement in a database using :

```
function void save(TraitementEntity obj){
 for (AnomalieEntity n : obj.getmListAnomalie()) {
                n.setTraitementForeign(obj);
            }

    create(obj);
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is when I need to save my traitement in local DB, it seems that I have nothing :

```
Log.i("OBJECT ANOMALIE SIZE", obj.getmListAnomalie().size() + ""); // gives 3
save(obj);

List<TraitementEntity> liste = mServiceLocal.getAllLocalTraitements();
for (TraitementEntity n : liste)
    Log.i("OBJECT ANOMALIE SIZE 2", n.getmListAnomalie().size() + ""); // gives always 0

/* This getmListeAnomalie() corresponds to the standard try/catch for queryForAll(), nothing else */
```

The traitement is well saved, but not the foreign anomalies.
So it's working partially, and I dont know why I have this behaviour.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm question.

In his TraitementEntity class does not contain **getmListAnomalie()** method
It is different from this :

```
for ( n AnomalieEntity : obj.getmListAnomalie ())
```

would not be

```
for ( AnomalieNettoyageEntity n : obj.mListAnomalieNettoyage ()) {
    n.setTraitementForeign ( obj) ;
}
```

Other options.
Load database SqlLite in managed, example (SqlLite browser) and checking tables is populated !

Please confirm, test !

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting `foreignAutoCreate = true` to the `DatabaseField` annotation like this:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "traitementForeignId", foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, canBeNull = false)
```

Here is the explanation from their [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html):

> Set this to be true (default false) to have the foreign field will be
>   automagically created using its internal DAO if the ID field is not
>   set (null or 0).

Comment: Have you tried creating the child items instead of the parent - i.e. try inserting the AnomalieEntity object. OrmLite should insert the Traitement automatically if I'm right.